# Prediction JSON payload Splunk alert

Tags: json, splunk, payload

At the moment I am busy working on something that requires input from a Splunk alert.

However, I am having trouble in discovering what the JSON output for the alert might be. I was wondering if anyone knows a way to predict JSON output accurately.

I know the specifics of the event that gives the alert and, of course, the details for the alert itself.

I am not allowed to share, unfortunately. I have a webhook, but it's not online yet, only reachable from localhost, because security has not been fitted appropriately yet. That's why I can't simply send an alert to test it.

Instead I want to send a curl with 'example' JSON output, but because there needs to be some decryption on that sample output, I would like for it to be quite accurate instead of simply taking a wild guess at it.

Is there anybody who can tell me how to predict the JSON payload?

Answer (score 0):

No need to guess the JSON payload, Splunk publishes the structure of the JSON messages made from webhook alert actions.

See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.5/Alert/Webhooks

Example:

```
{

    "result": {
        "sourcetype" : "mongod",
        "count" : "8"
    },
    "sid" : "scheduler_admin_search_W2_at_14232356_132",
    "results_link" : "http://web.example.local:8000/app/search/@go?sid=scheduler_admin_search_W2_at_14232356_132",
    "search_name" : null,
    "owner" : "admin",
    "app" : "search"
}
```

*If this fixes your problem, take a moment to accept the answer. This can be done by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in!*